# Save button is disabled while creating collection and adding first document in firebase database. Why?

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-console

Save button is disabled when I tried to create a collection and add it's first document.
[Here you can see in the image even after selecting Auto-ID option, still save button is disabled. Please help me if anyone know's what is actual reasson behind that.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7P3xx.png)

Comment: Can you try to hard refresh (Ctrl + shift + r)? also if you're asking questions attach the picture on your question and put the description as a text not a link. You may refer to this link on [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).